# Having problems with the logic in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I having a problem with the logic problem on checkfirstnamecount!=1 for example:

```
DELIMITER go
    /* Passing the parameters */
    /*  I still get firstname error message every time I tried to execute*/
    Create procedure registerusers(
      Out UserID tinyint(11),
     IN iFirstName varchar(30),
     IN iLastName varchar(30),
     IN iPassword varchar(30),
     IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
     IN iSalt varchar(40),
     IN iRoleID varchar(1))
    BEGIN
    /* declaring thecheckfirstnamecount for counting first name*/
    declare checkfirstnamecount int;
    select count(FirstName) into checkfirstnamecount
    from users
    where FirstName = iFirstName;
    /*checking if the count firstname is not equal to 1 */
     /* if count 1 is not equal to count 1 then it should display the message*/   
    If(checkfirstnamecount!=1) then

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';

    else

    insert into users(
        /* insert into user if its not empty */
    FirstName,
     LastName ,
     Password ,
     EmailAddress ,
     Salt ,
     RoleID 
     )
    Values
    (
    iFirstName,
     iLastName ,
     iPassword ,
     iEmailAddress ,
     iSalt ,
     iRoleID 
    );
    set UserID = last_insert_id();  
     end if;

    End
    go
    DELIMITER ;
```

The result is that it does execute but whenever I pass on

```
call registerusers(@new_id,'Jerry','Johnson','5566','johnson@gmail.com','1243','U');
```

I kept seeing the same display message that says:

> fill out the first name

It suppose to execute the insert data.

Answer (score 0):

Check your procedure code as pointed below. So the first name `Jerry` matches multiple records and thus the end result.

```
If(checkfirstnamecount!=1) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';
```

Where your local variable `checkfirstnamecount` getting filled by below query

```
select count(FirstName) into checkfirstnamecount
from users
where FirstName = iFirstName;
```

I feel, you meant to check if there is no record exists with that first name then insert this record and in that case your condition should actually be

```
If(checkfirstnamecount <> 0) then
  //PRINT error message
ELSE
   //perform insertion
```

Comment: I tested the count for first name on jerry like this: select count(FirstName) into checkfirstnamecount
from users
where FirstName = 'jerry'; the result for count is 2 and I've tried If(checkfirstnamecount = 0) and this time I tried call registerusers(@new_id,'Jerry','Johnson','5566','johnson@gmail.com','1243','U'); and the result is I kept getting the same message saying "fill out the first name "

Comment: @DavidJones, that's correct, since there is already record present with that name it shouldn't perform insertion

Comment: it suppose to insert the data and what if the person have same firstname but different last name.  It is like this If(checkfirstnamecount=0) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';

Comment: If I pass set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'Jeremy','James','5566','andrew@gmail.com','sdfd','U');
select @new_id;  I still kept getting the same message like fill out the first name. I bascially want to insert the data. I bascially wrote If(checkfirstnamecount=0) for if the firstname is empty.

Comment: if I want to insert the data like this:set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'Jeremy','James','5566','andrew@gmail.com','sdfd','U');
select @new_id; it should go through

Comment: @DavidJones, include both first and lastname in your condition like `select count(*) into checkfirstnamecount
    from users
    where FirstName = iFirstName and LastName=iLastName;`

Comment: It did work on using the same firstname and lastname but it didn't work on the different firstname and lastname. I bascially want to insert data and checking the error message if the firstname is empty set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'','James','5566','andrew@gmail.com','sdfd','U');
select @new_id;  it should display an error message and it should insert the data if the first name is filled.